# How to declare and use fixed size char buffer in C# struct

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I have the following struct declaration:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyDLLInput
{
    ...
    public fixed char PathtoData[256];
};
```

PathtoData shows an error as-is:

```
"Pointers and fixed-size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context."
```

MyDLLInput is passed to a C++ DLL:

```
public class MyDLL
{
    [DllImport("MyDLL.dll",
        EntryPoint = "?Unit@@YA?AUOutput@@UInput@@@Z",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern MyDLLOutput Unit(MyDLLInput UnitInput);
}
```

MyDLL.h defines the member as:

```
char PathtoData[256];
```

How do I make the member declaration properly in my C# code?

Comment: Could you show full C++ class with member PathToData? Also why don't use [Exporting C++ Functions for Use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf2w9f6x.aspx) instead of mangled function names like "?Unit@@YA?AUOutput@@UInput@@@Z" ?

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan The C++ DLL is provided to me by another developer. I don't have the source code, although I could obtain it. I don't know C++ well enough to do what you suggest. The mangled name was made available to me via Dependency Walker.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan But I am going to forward your link to the developer of that C++ DLL. The mangled name doesn't bother me much really. Once it's in place it is out of sight, but I do like your suggestion.

Comment: why I have asked about C++ codes, because I'm not sure that you need unsafe here. It's just P/Invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it said:

> Pointers and fixed-size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context.

so in order to use fixed size char buffer like this you need to add `unsafe` to your struct:

```
public unsafe struct MyDLLInput
{
   ...
   public fixed char PathtoData[256];
};
```

you also need to allow unsafe compiling like this:

1. Right click on your project.
2. Select "Properties".
3. Switch to the "Build" tab.
4. Check "Allow unsafe code"

According to [MSDN - Unsafe Code and Pointers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx)

> In the common language runtime (CLR), unsafe code is referred to as unverifiable code. Unsafe code in C# is not necessarily dangerous; it is just code whose safety cannot be verified by the CLR. The CLR will therefore only execute unsafe code if it is in a fully trusted assembly. If you use unsafe code, it is your responsibility to ensure that your code does not introduce security risks or pointer errors.

for more information and comparison of safe and unsafe code you can also check
 [Safe and Unsafe Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228628(v=vs.90).aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: I've never used `unsafe`. Your example takes care of all errors. Is there a simple explanation for how `unsafe` effects the rest of the app? Or will this setting effect only code marked with the `unsafe` attribute?

Comment: Also note that char in C++ is usually 8 bit (platform dependent) but in C# is 16 bit (wchar_t in C++ if on Windows). In short: change type to byte and handle encoding conversion.

Comment: @rwkiii, I updated the answer, however you should consider encoding conversion as Adriano mentioned is his comment.

Comment: @hsh Yes, I have set it for byte. Thank you to both of you. This is all very helpful.